# How do I debug a SQL View in Visual Studio? Symbols not loaded

Tags: sql, debugging, visual-studio-2013, view

I am inside Server explorer. I Have Altered the view and set a break point. It says:
no symbols have been loaded for this document.

How do I get debug symbols to load for debug database objects?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use "SQL Server Object Explorer", browse to the instance and database that you want to debug the code in.

When you find the database, right click it and choose "New Query" - then type the SQL that you want to debug i.e. exec proc or insert into table_with_trigger

Set a breakpoint on the code then do Alt+F5 or hit the Debug query button.

Visual Studio should then break on your breakpoint, F11 into the code you actually want to debug and once that opens you are free to set the breakpoints wherever you want them.

Two things to bear in mind:

- It isn't like a c# project you don't debug the files on your machine instead you are debugging a sql_module that has an object_id in a sql server instance. That is why you are getting the error about no symbols being loaded.
- I don't think you can step into views, you can step into stored procs and triggers though

ed